# Creating onlink route via bridged adapter unexpected behavior

Tags: linux-networking, ip, bridge, route

I am trying to create an onlink connection between a Windows host and a Linux vm guest in VirtualBox using a bridged network adapter. The IP on the guest 10.x.x.x. The IP on the host is 192.x.x.x.
I do the following:

1. On host `route add 10.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0`.

Result: I can't ping 10.x.x.x on host. (unexpected)

2. On guest `sudo ip route add 192.x.x.x via 10.x.x.1 dev enp0s9 onlink`. (The gateway is set for the interface, but gateway is fake and doesn't exist on network. I needed to specify gateway because `ip` doesn't want to onlink without an existing gateway (`Error: Invalid flags for nexthop - PERVASIVE and ONLINK can not be set.` is the error I get if I use 0.0.0.0)).

Result: I can't ping 10.x.x.x on host. (unexpected)

3. On guest I remove previous entry and instead do `sudo ip route add 192.168.2.6 via 0.0.0.0 dev enp0s9`

Result: Despite `ip route` showing the new entry not having onlink I can ping 10.x.x.x on host. (unexpected)

If after 3 I then remove the entry created in 1 and try pinging 10.x.x.x, the pinging fails.

Why do I need to make a route on the guest in the first place? Why can't I ping from host with 2? I thought onlink was supposed to bypass the gateway. Why does 3 work?

After any of this I can't ping 192.x.x.x from the guest (I'm fine with that, but it doesn't make sense), but the software I am running on the guest is able to establish connection from host (which is what I want, but I am uncertain of why and a little how).

Comment: When using a bridged adapter you share the Ethernet adapter of the host with the VM. So I wouldn't change the default routing table unless you have very special requirements.